# My dimple chart doesn't appear with Firefox, only with chrome. Visualization problems

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm programming with dimple to paint some charts with meteo data in real time. I have got to paint charts with google chrome, but now, i'm testing the charts with firefox, and i can't see the charts. It seems that the svg is placed in a place outside of my div. I have tried with percents and with pixels, but it's impossible. Have I to add some directives to work with firefox?

Comment: I have the next chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/zFzV8/82/

If i execute this file with firefox, the chart doesn't appear correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of dimple.  Please use http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.3.min.js instead.